# Donating ESPP shares to non-profit organization

Tags: united-states, donation, espp

In recent years, I've made donations to some non-profit organizations using stock shares.  They immediately sell when they receive the shares from my brokerage firm and send me a document at the end of the year showing how much they sold it for for tax purposes.

Can I donate ESPP shares to a non-profit organization like I can with normal stock shares or is it different since it's ESPP and sold to me with a 15% discount?

If it IS different, what is the normal process I should do when donating ESPP shares?